# Assign customers to shops. Shops have maximum assigned customers

Tags: sql-server-2008

Overview:

I have shops with defined radius (20 miles). I have customers. If a customer is within 20 miles from a shop, the customer is assigned to this shop. If one customer is within 20 miles from more than 1 shop, the customer is assigned to the shop that the customer spend most money to.

The above is implemented and working fine. But now I have new requirement, I need help with. The shops now have limit of maximum number of assigned customers.
So my problem is when a customer can be assigned to two shops, and the customer is suppose to be assigned to the because of most money spend, but this shop already reached the maximum number of assigned customers. In this case the customer must be assigned to shop2

Query so far:

```
-- assigned all customers to all shops
INSERT  INTO #assignment
        SELECT  cd.ap_business_id ,
                cb.customer_id ,
                dist.distance
        FROM    shops cd
                CROSS JOIN customer cb
                JOIN ZipDistance dist ON dist.zip1 = cd.business_zip
                                         AND cb.zip = dist.zip2

-- If customer is assigned to more than one shop, keep the assignment to the shop that is closest to the customer
-- or to the shop where the customer spends most money. Remove other assignments.
;
WITH    CTE
          AS ( SELECT   a.ap_business_id ,
                        a.customer_id ,
                        a.vehicle_id ,
                        ROUND(a.distance, 1) AS distance ,
                        db$.max_dealer_net_sales AS total1 ,
                        b$.max_dealer_net_sales AS total2 ,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY a.customer_id ORDER BY ROUND(a.distance,
                                                              1) ASC, ISNULL(c$.max_shop_net_sales,
                                                              0) DESC, a.customer_id ) AS RN
               FROM     #assignment a -- total $ that given Business spend for collision parts
                        LEFT JOIN ( SELECT  ap_business_id ,
                                            SUM(amount) AS max_customer_net_sales
                                    FROM    customer_payments iq
                                    WHERE   iq.close_date > DATEADD(YEAR, -1,
                                                              GETDATE())
                                    GROUP BY iq.ap_business_id
                                  ) c$ ON c$.ap_business_id = a.ap_business_id
               WHERE    a.customer_id IN ( SELECT   vehicle_id
                                           FROM     #assignment aa
                                           GROUP BY aa.customer_id
                                           HAVING   COUNT(*) > 1 )
             )
    DELETE  #assignment
    FROM    #assignment a
            JOIN CTE c ON a.ap_business_id = c.ap_business_id
                          AND a.customer_id = c.customer_id
                          AND c.RN > 1
```

Comment: if your number of assigned customers changes during assigning, then I don't see a way to do it without loop, recursive query

Comment: I think by adding one more filter condition might work. count(customers) < max_assignedcustomer, consider only those records...